# How to make the suggestion box appear?

Tags: functions, keyboard, autocomplete

When you type a function in Matlab, quickly a suggestion box comes up showing functions similar to the one you're typing. I thought that Mathematica didn't have this but one day, I typed half of a function and the went to the kitchen when I got back, the suggestion box was there. I'm not sure if it appears after some time or if I accidentaly pressed some key.

Comment: By default, you don't need to do anything in Mathematica 9: as soon as you begin typing a function name, a possible list of completions will pop up without your doing anything. And this "predictive interface" allegedly learns from which completions you use most often.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>?

After typing `Plo`, press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and a window will appear with possible options:

[image]

As pointed by Yves，<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> will also work，but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> will work differently if you finish the function name. For an example,

1. Type Plot3D;
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>;

Mathematica will show:

[image]

Comment: ...and it's quite useful since Mathematica functions average about 57 times more letters than Matlab's

Comment: This is perfect, and it was exactly the kind of thing I was searching for. I guess my hypothesis of accidentaly pressing the keys is fairly invalid now. I also *remember* that the box I saw was pretty different, an allucination maybe?

Comment: Perhaps we should employ [infinite monkeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) to get all of them funky shortcuts ;-)

Comment: +1 because I keep forgetting to use Ctrl+Shift+K!  That could really improve my speed of entry.  Now I just need to figure out how to make it give me ~infix~ ... :^)

Comment: And on the Mac it is Cmd+Shift+K.

Answer (score 13):

Besides the nice real handy option suggested by @yulinlinyu ([more here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/SelectingAndTypingInNotebooks.html)) you can also use [**text-based interface**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GettingInformationAboutMathematicaObjects.html) to find completion for your half-typed function. It is not that fast, but has its own advantages. Try executing this:

```
?Plot*
```

[image]

and you'll get this nice table of possible functions that complete your input. If you click on any you'll get short definition - as you can see below. And if you click on `>>` sign at the very end you'll get full Documentation Center article. Sometimes this is really handy, because you can take time clicking various definitions and do completion from other side:

```
?*Graph
```

[image]

This is how, for example, I discovered that *Mathematica* supports the awesome [`DeBruijnGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Combinatorica/ref/DeBruijnGraph.html) (definition shown above). And of course you can generalize further:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes instead of handy shorthands like in the other answers, you'll find more useful [`Names`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Names.html) giving a list of the names of symbols matching the string, (it's case sensitive of course) e.g.

```
Names["Gro*B*"]
Names["Gro*b*"]
```

> ```
> {"GroebnerBasis", "GroupActionBase", "GroupPageBreakWithin"}
>
> {"GroebnerBasis", "GroupMultiplicationTable", "GroupOrbits",
>  "GroupSetwiseStabilizer", "GroupStabilizer", "GroupStabilizerChain"}
> ```

If you want to look at the documentation of a given name :

1. highlight its name e.g `GroupActionBase`
2. then press <kbd>F1</kbd>

`Names` can be useful in many cases e.g. when you'd like to select only names with  special `Attributes`, or to figure out how many specific symbols there are.

```
Select[Names["G*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &]
```

> ```
> {"Gamma", "GammaRegularized", "GegenbauerC", "Gudermannian"}
> ```

To count the number of names let's define :

```
f = Length @ Names @ # &;
```

e.g.  in `Mathematica 8`

```
f /@ { "*G*", "Gr*", "Gra*", "Graph*", "*Graph*" }
```

> ```
> {348, 99, 56, 52, 113}
> ```

in `Mathematica 7` there were less of them

```
f /@ { "*G*", "Gr*", "Gra*", "Graph*", "*Graph*" }
```

> ```
> {200, 64, 34, 30, 38}
> ```

Comment: Did you evaluate the last piece of code in Mathematica 7, or is there a way to tell Mathematica to pretend it is version 7?

Comment: That was evaluated in `Mathematica 7` and `8` respectively. You can find e.g. `New in 8.0: Alphabetical Listing` : http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NewIn80AlphabeticalListing.html so it is possible to count the new functions programmatically, although I found it more straightforward to evaluate `f` in the both versions separately.